# mvc - google map need to show all users in map by lat and long data

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, asp.net-web-api, google-maps-api-3

**google map need to show all users in map by lat and long data**

> ```
> // Data returned as response
> ```

```
window.onload = function(){
    fun_ShowUsers();
};

function fun_ShowUsers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (response) {
            {
                var responseLength = response.length;
                var htmlString = '';
                $('Body').append('<input type="hidden" value="' + responseLength + '" />');
                for (var i = 0; i < responseLength - 1; i++) {
                    htmlString += '<input id="'+i+'" class="MapLocation" type="hidden" data-lat="' + response[i].Lat + '" data-long="' + response[i].Long + '" />';
                }
                $('myBody').html(htmlString);

                fun_ShowInMap(); // How ??
            }
        }
    });
};

function fun_ShowInMap() {
 How i can do that .....
     How i can show all users in map using lat and long from db exists..
     I need to help plz
};
```

[This Image is have one mark by one lat and long im don't need to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc0cz.png) 
***i need to show many marks in map***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: thx it's good @HoangHieu

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
<head>
  
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="height: 400px; width: 500px;">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [this image have error][1]


[this image have full simply code][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HEZb.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cooU.png

that is not work i'm don't know how can do that ... :(

Comment: not work , but i wish this way be truth because it is very simple,